# Why an <hr> is different in prod than in watch mode?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, html-email

I work on email template for our internal newsletter and I want to use Framework specially created for creating best html emails, [Foundation for Emails 2](http://foundation.zurb.com/emails.html).

It's great, but I have problem with `<hr>` element. I want to give to it 100% width. If I run it in `watch` mode, it works:

[image]

But If I run `build` task, it's like this (it's shorter) and I really don't know why:

[image]

Is there someone who has more experience with this framework?

**Inky:**

```
<container>
    <row>
        <columns class="bigger-space line" large="12">
            <hr />
        </columns>
    </row>
</container>
```

**Relevant CSS:**

```
.bigger-space {
  padding-right: 30px !important;
  padding-left: 30px !important;
}

.line {
  padding-bottom: 30px !important;

  tbody tr th:first-child {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}
```

**Generated HTML in watch mode:**

```
<!-- SEPARATOR LINE -->
<table class="container float-center"><tbody><tr><td>
<table class="row"><tbody><tr>
    <th class="bigger-space line small-12 large-12 columns first last">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <hr>
        </th>
        <th class="expander"></th>
       </tr>
     </table>
   </th>
</tr></tbody></table>
```

**Generated HTML in build mode:**

```
<table class="container float-center" style="-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;Margin:0 auto;background:#fefefe;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;float:none;font-weight:400!important;margin:0 auto;padding:0;text-align:center;vertical-align:top;width:500px"><tbody><tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top"><td style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-hyphens:auto;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;Margin:0;border-collapse:collapse!important;color:#0a0a0a;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:400!important;hyphens:auto;line-height:19px;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"><table class="row" style="-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;display:table;font-weight:400!important;padding:0;position:relative;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%"><tbody><tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top"><th class="bigger-space line small-12 large-12 columns first last" style="Margin:0 auto;color:#0a0a0a;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:400;line-height:19px;margin:0 auto;padding:0;padding-bottom:30px!important;padding-left:30px!important;padding-right:30px!important;text-align:left;width:500px"><table style="-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;font-weight:400!important;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%"><tbody><tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top"><th style="Margin:0;color:#0a0a0a;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:400;line-height:19px;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left"><hr style="Margin:20px auto;border-bottom:1px solid #cacaca;border-left:0;border-right:0;border-top:0;clear:both;height:0;margin:0!important;max-width:500px"></th><th class="expander" style="Margin:0;color:#0a0a0a;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:400;line-height:19px;margin:0;padding:0!important;text-align:left;visibility:hidden;width:0"></th></tr></tbody></table></th></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: Maybe some wrapper that is not 100%?

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: I assume this is with something like Grunt? Most likely your "watch" task isn't doing as much as your "build" task. Take a look at your config; maybe build is doing extra minification and autoprefixer tasks which aren't being done in watch.

Answer (score 1):

I just found one fix for it, it is and issue of Zurb Framework: https://github.com/zurb/foundation-emails/issues/434.

**HTML:**

```
<row>
  <columns>
    <p class="hr-fix">&nbsp;</p>
    <hr>
  </columns>
</row>
```

**CSS:**

```
.hr-fix{
  line-height: 0px !important;
}
```

Sorry about it, I should look into issue first, next time.

Comment: Please include the releveant parts here, as the linked page might change and/or disapear.